# Angular 4 checkbox trigger change event on model change

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" [(ngModel)]="filter" (change)="onFilterChange($event)"> CheckBox

<button (click)="filter = !filter">Change Status</button>
```

**TS**

```
export class HelloWorld {

  filter : false;

  onFilterChange() {
    console.log('filter change called');
  }
}
```

When I directly click on the check box change event is triggered. But when I click on "Change Status" button checkbox status is changing but change event is not triggering. Can some one please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We have to achieve this functionality with event handler and not with 2 way binding

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1"
       [ngModel]="filter" (ngModelChange)="onFilterChange($event)"> Checkbox

<button (click)="onFilterChange($event)">Change Status</button>
```

and in TS,

```
export class HelloWorld {

  filter = false;

  onFilterChange(eve: any) {
    this.filter = !this.filter;
  }
}
```

Comment: @PratapA.K your onFilterChange expects a parameter, check the updated answer

Comment: still it's not working!! Can u please give me a plnkr if it is working for you?

Comment: yea!! Thanks for the help